# Setting the TTL (expire) using new Redis-OM & Node Object Mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, orm, ttl

I came across the new Redis-OM Node Object Mapping functionality, I've not really experimented with Redis before but I thought now might be the time to give it a go.

Right now I have a basic function set up for creating a room but I would like the room to expire after say 24 hours (86400 seconds iirc).

```js
export async function createRoom(data) {
    await connect();

    const repository = new Repository(schema, client);

    const room = repository.createEntity(data);

    const id = await repository.save(room);

    return id;
}
```

How do I set the TTL or expire time for an object using the Object Mapping approach... see my schema below.

```js
class Room extends Entity {}
let schema = new Schema(
    Room,
    {
        code: { type: 'string' },
        playlist: { type: 'array', videos: { type: 'string' } },
    },
    {
        dataStructure: 'JSON',
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, Redis OM doesn't support setting the TTL as part of object mapping but I think it's a good idea and will put it in the backlog.

For now, you can set it manually using the `Client.execute()` method to call EXPIRE on the key containing the object you want to expire.

Details on the EXPIRE command are [here](https://redis.io/commands/expire) but it's pretty much just `EXPIRE key seconds`.

They key for objects in Redis OM for Node.js is made up of the entity name and the entity ID separated by a colon. So, in your example, this would be something like `Room:01FT4JWNQ2FJHQEVWXNRMWZ2QR`.

Putting this together, here's the magic line of code:

```
await client.execute(['EXPIRE', `Room:${id}`, 3600]);
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks @Guy Rose!

Comment: Thanks Guy Rose. Are there plans for Redis OM to support updating the TTL using SaveAsync(), something like collection.SaveAsync(new TimeSpan(0,0,0))

Comment: That'd be for Redis OM .NET. Not my bailiwick. This discussion is about  Redis OM for Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
await repository.expire(id.toString(), 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer, so people will understand why you proposed it.